# CrateDB create custom analyzer

Tags: crate, cratedb

I'm trying to create a custom analyzer, following the syntax from https://crate.io/docs/crate/reference/en/latest/sql/statements/create-analyzer.html however when I attempt to create the following :

```
create analyzer FullAddressAnalyzer ([TOKENIZER ngram with (min_gram = 2, max_gram =10)])
```

I get the `SQLActionException[SQLParseException: tokenizer name 'ngram' is reserved]` error, this baffles me as the documentation explains that you can use parameters for ngram but this doesn't seem to make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the CrateDB SQL reference documentation is not correct for this case.

When creating a custom analyzer with a parameterized tokenizer, one must use a custom name for the tokenizer while defining the type of the tokenizer. Example:

```
create analyzer full_address_analyzer (TOKENIZER my_ngram with (type = ngram, min_gram = 2, max_gram =10)])
```